# in QT in field of Signals & Slots, What signal should I put in the connect command when i solving the dynamic equation in "Real time"؟

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qobject, qapplication

I simulated a dynamical device like mass spring damper.the QT Solves the equation of motion in Real Time and displays the output. I want to use an Qapplication object,to display Data and the outputs in "Real time". I don't know What should I put the "signal type"  " in connect command"  for this aim.(The answer in my opinion will probably be one of the method of QGraphicsRectItem class - Something is changing here is RectItem Position).

the main class is:

```
#include "QTcpSocket"
#include "QHostAddress"
#include "QObject"
#include "QThread"

Pltaform::Pltaform()
{
   GraphicMass = new Motion();
   iTH = new QThread;
}

void Pltaform::run()
{

isRunning = true;
while (isRunning)
{

    switch (&message)
    {
    case 1:
        getWorldData();
        break;

    case 2:
        calculateControls();
        DisplayQGraphic();
        sendPlatformData();
        break;

    case 3:
        isRunning = false;
        cout << "Simulation Finished." << endl;
        break;


 void Pltaform::DisplayQGraphic()
 {
GraphicMass->pos_x = states(0);
GraphicMass->pos_y = states(1);

 // connect
 GraphicMass->moveToThread(iTH);

 connect(GraphicMass,SIGNAL(?????),this,SLOT(move()));

 iTH->start();
}

void Pltaform::move()
{
setPos(x()+GraphicMass->pos_x,y()-GraphicMass>pos_y);
}
```

and the Motion class is:

```
#include "QGraphicsScene"
#include "QGraphicsView"
#include "QGraphicsRectItem"
#include "QObject"

 Motion::Motion()
 {
 // create an item to put into the scene
 setRect(0,0,20,30);
 setPos(x(),y());

 pos_x = 0;
 pos_y = 0;}
```

Comment: ***What signal should I put in the connect command when i solving the dynamic equation in “Real time”؟** I am unsure how we are possibly going to know that. We don't have your code. You most likely need to produce a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

`QGraphichsRectItem` and any of its parent classes don't have any implemented signals. So, you need to emit your own signal(s) by inheriting `Qt` class into your own new class, that you'll use it.
I'm not sure how this will be done because I couldn't see the code, but I may predict that you need to reimplement `setRect()` or any other function that implements the moving operation, just call the super function and emit the signal at its end.